# which is best coding practice, assigning to the variable or fetch from database

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

in my coding snippets

**customer.java**

```
  public class customer{

   private Double avgSalePrice;
   private Double costOfScrap;
   private Double minCastingWt;


    //getters and setters
 }
```

bussiness logic

**first way :**

```
public HashMap<String, Object> prepareCustomer() {

  Integer customerPkey=1;
  HashMap<String, Object> responseMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();

  //get the customer object from the data base and assigning scrapCost to responseMap from getterProperty
  responseMap.put("scrapCost",customerService.readCustomerInfo(customerPkey).getCostOfScrap());

  //get the customer object from the data base  and assigning scrapCost to responseMap from getterProperty
  responseMap.put("salePrice",customerService.readCustomerInfo(customerPkey).getAvgSalePrice());

  //get the customer object from the data base  and assigning minCastingWt to responseMap  from getterProperty
  responseMap.put("minCastingWt",customerService.readCustomerInfo(customerPkey).getMinCastingWt());

    return responseMap;
}
```

**second way:**

```
public HashMap<String, Object> prepareCustomer() {

  Integer customerPkey=1;

  HashMap<String, Object> responseMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();

  Customer customer = customerService.readCustomerInfo(customerPkey);

  responseMap.put("scrapCost",customer.getScrapCost());
  responseMap.put("salePrice",customer.getSalePrice());
  responseMap.put("minCastingWt",customer.getMinCastingWt());

  return responseMap;
}
```

**Now My Doubt is**

1.fetch the customer row from the data base and assigning to the HashMap  for all three time is a best practice(showned in first way)

**(OR)**

2.fetch the customer row from the data base for single fetch then assigning to the Customer Object and use the reference of the object to put all three value in responseMap is a best practice (showned in second way)

i need a clear explanation for timing and memory allocation for the both two ways

Thanks in advance ...  :)

Comment: do you really want to do x calls to the backend to retrieve the same data, while you can just do it in one time?

Comment: i need clear explantion @Stultuske

Comment: how much clearer than that do you need it? you want to set three fields, for each of them you perform a call to your customerService, which no doubt does a lookup in your db. how about you do that once, and based on that, you get the customers specifics, instead of asking the same data from the db for each specific you want to set

Comment: much better author #stultuske

Comment: Your question makes no sense.  It is exactly equivalent to this: _"I want to drink three beers.  Should I buy THREE six-packs and drink one beer from each one, discarding the rest; or should I buy ONE six-pack and drink three beers from that six-pack?"_

Comment: Why would you want store the properties of an object in a map???

Comment: Yeah but i didn't know which is best one so only ask here for expert beer drinker like you @JimGarrison

Comment: for return it  into my UI @TomVanRossom

Comment: And the UI cannot handle an object?

Comment: What possible reason would anyone have to use option 1 (or even *think* of using it)? Please edit your question to include this information.

Comment: we use jquery to handle object in UI @TomVanRossom

Comment: Can't you just convert the customer-object to json, instead to a map? If you are using spring-mvc, this is done automatically!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is here:

```
public HashMap<String, Object> prepareCustomer(Customer customer) {
  HashMap<String, Object> responseMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();

  responseMap.put("scrapCost", customer.getScrapCost());
  responseMap.put("salePrice", customer.getSalePrice());
  responseMap.put("minCastingWt", customer.getMinCastingWt());

  return responseMap;
}
```

> fetch the customer row from the data base and assigning to the HashMap for all three time

`Customer` will not be fetched from the database three times. It will be fetched only once and for all subsequent requests for the customer the same customer will be returned from the `Session`. The `Session` is so called the first level cache.

Even if you make three calls for the same Customer, it takes the same time and memory as, if you call for the Customer once.

You can  use `ImmutableMap` from guava to construct the `Map`:

```
ImmutableMap.of("scrapCost", customer.getScrapCost(),
                "salePrice", customer.getSalePrice(),
                "minCastingWt", customer.getMinCastingWt());
```

Comment: very informatic